# Can not run spring boot application using the bat file on windows

Tags: spring-boot, batch-file

Here is my run.bat file content

```
title data-middleware

@set JAVA_HOME=D:\java\jdk1.8.0_181
@set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

java -jar D:\data-middleware\data-middleware.jar --spring.profiles.active=private,test
```

If I click on that file twice it works(program starts).
But my problem is that I want to run it using third party app. So I use this command

```
start call D:\data-middleware\run.bat
```

Somehow it doesn't recognize profile configuration and shows the relevant error message. It was happy until I changed and tried to use two profiles(private,test)

```
java -jar D:\data-middleware\data-middleware.jar --spring.profiles.active=test
```

Any ideas why it's happening. Maybe bat files are not suitable with commas? Does someone have any idea?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: It can't take url parameter from profile configuration to create data source. It worked well until I had one profile

Comment: It also tries to run on 8080 port instead of my custom port. It doesn't recognize profile configurations

Comment: it is difficult to replicate the problem, but what happens when you try setting a default profile, maybe something like: `--spring.profiles.default=private` I am, not saying it will fix the issue, I need to see if that makes any difference to the behaviour.

Comment: Same result. I am not sure but I thinks it's windows based issue. dbl-click on the bat file and execution it from the command line have to have same result as I know

Comment: ok, so now, what is the third party app you are referring to?

Comment: This app is called Jenkins. But first of all I am trying to call it from Command line(windows cmd) on the same machine where the app is located

Comment: I use "start call" because I want to run this app in the new session(new cmd window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed .bat file content and magically it started working

```
title data-middleware

@set JAVA_HOME=D:\java\jdk1.8.0_181
@set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

D:
cd data-middleware\
java -jar data-middleware.jar --spring.profiles.active=private,test
exit
```